# Excel data validation to use list based on value in other cell using indirect reference

Tags: excel

If I put `=IF(B1="My Value";ListA;ListB)` or `=IF(INDIRECT("B1")="My Value";ListA;ListB)` into a data validation on cell A1, it works. But if I put `=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+1))="My Value";ListA;ListB)` it throws an error.

Does anyone have idea why it works like that?

Edit: The reason why I need it to be indirect and relative to the cell is that people that use the spreadsheet can copy and paste values in the spreadsheet, but I need the references to stay untouched.

Edit2: As a general rule of thumb, I noticed that everything works better if I put the logic into a named range and refer the named range in data validation formula. Some functions just won't work in data validation formula, but they work in named range.

Comment: What's ListA and B, just a range of cells, rows only?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If `=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+1))="My Value";ListA;ListB)` is the validation for cell `A1`, then the part `ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+1)` is referring to cell `B1`, not cell `A2`.

Comment: I presumed this was just a type-o. It doesn't work if you modify to `Row()+1` either.

Comment: Oh yeah. I meant B1, not A2.

Comment: @pgSystemTester Yeah, ListA and ListB are just a range of cells. One column several rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know WHY it works like that, but my best guess is that it has something related to using `row()` within a cell that doesn't exist. However, there is a workaround to what you're trying to do by creating a specif RELATIVE named range and making that part of your validation. This results in exactly the same thing as what your failed formula is trying to accomplish.

See [this spreadsheet for an example](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g7MKB04CS4dwZkT9dQ?e=GUeE1J).

### Relative Named Range

Named ranges are mostly used to identify locked or specific ranges. But you can use them to create relative references. Example in above spreadsheet is a relative named range of `oneCellBelow`. This is a named range that will always reference the cell below it. To make this, see the below screenshot that has the selected cell of `H5` but has a reference to `H6` without the absolute $. This will result in always referencing the cell below it.

**Update Based On Comments**
To use a relative named range of one cell to the right, the below screenshot should Refer to: `Sheet1!i5` instad of `Sheet1!H6`.

[image]

Here's an image of what it should look like when completed:

[image]

### Validation

As I said above, I don't know why using the relative named range works, and the `Row()` indirect does not, but you can use the above named range to create your relative validation.

Using your example, the validation formula could be written as:

```
=IF(oneCellBelow="My Value";ListA;ListB)
```

Hopefully that gets the end result you need. In the example file you can see two different cells using the same validation, but with different results.

Comment: Thanks. The named range works. But I actually need to copy this to hundreds of cells that each refer to a cell next to them. So, I would like to find a solution that does not make me do hundreds of named ranges.

Comment: @Mika So... yeah that's exactly what this does. I modified the above spreadsheet to include a new named Range of `OneCellToRight` and copied the validation into hundreds of cells. Each one operates exactly as you describe...

Comment: Maybe I can define one named range that covers all the cells that I need to refer and use INDEX or something to pick the one that I need.

Comment: Now I see how that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ah, yes, now I recall. For some reason if the reference passed to `INDIRECT` is not **static**, then it needs to be stored as a **Defined Name** in order to be passed to a Data Validation list.

So you will need to define *MyCheck* (say) as:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1)+1))`

(It goes without saying that you need to create this Name whilst the active cell in the worksheet is `A1`.)

After which the Data Validation List formula is:

`=IF(MyCheck="My Value",ListA,ListB)`

Comment: That's not a bad answer, however having named range include indirect will use more overhead as a volatile function than using a specific relative named range as my answer illustrates. Don't ask why this is (doesn't make sense to me), but I tested this with incredible curiousity a couple years ago and it's definitely more effecient to use relative named range than ever using `Indirect.` (maybe I should make a post about this)

Comment: I completely agree. I always avoid volatile functions. I was simply curious from a theoretical point of view as to how it could be made to work with INDIRECT. However, if you have a valid, non-volatile alternative then it should absolutely be preferred.

Comment: yea my answer does exactly that. I upvoted yours as it's still good.